# MySQL Corrupted After System Crash

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, corruption

I'm using MacOS Monterey 12.6.1 with Homebrew 3.6.6 and MariaDB 10.8.3

The OS crashed out of nowhere and rebooted itself. After the reboot I was unable to connect to the database: *Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)*

Current results of "mysqld" command:

```
[Note] mysqld (server 10.8.3-MariaDB) starting as process 12300 ...
[Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ is case 
[Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
[Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
[Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
[Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
[ERROR] InnoDB: Upgrade after a crash is not supported. The redo log was created with MariaDB 
[ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
[Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
[ERROR] Aborting
```

And the error log is as follows:

```
mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/crtx.pid ended
mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
[Note] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mariadb/10.8.3_1/bin/mariadbd (server 10.8.3-MariaDB) starting as process 9036 ...
[Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
[Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 1 !!!
[Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
[Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
[Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
[Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
[ERROR] InnoDB: File ./ib_logfile0 was not found
[ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
[Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
[ERROR] Aborting
```

I upgraded to the new MariaDB version via Homebrew but it didn't work because it was corrupted. As far as I understand it is not possible to downgrade to its original version anymore.

I tried the ib_logfile* deletion method but it didn't work. I tried to fix it by giving "innodb_force_recovery=1 / 2 / 3" parameters in my.cnf, the result is frustration again.

I have 1 month of work inside and I don't have up-to-date backup.

Is there any way to fix the server and get it working again?

Or at least recover the database inside? That way I can do a clean install and create the tables again...

Comment: @RobertLongson `Warning: mariadb@10.7 has been deprecated because it is not supported upstream!`

Comment: @RobertLongson The previous version could no longer be installed because it's deprecated. If I do uninstall-reinstall, won't all databases be completely deleted? My goal is just to be able to recover the data inside.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you for your guidance. I've successfully downgraded to the relevant version but another problem occurred now. So I'll continue with a new topic.

Comment: OK, I've converted my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to

```
brew uninstall mariadb
brew install mariadb@10.7
```

That will install the old version and yet keep your databases. The Upgrade after a crash is not supported error should then go away.